# What prevents a tilt and turn window from falling down on me?

Tags: windows

We have tilt and turn windows in our flat and I'm always afraid it falls on me when the handle is between the two positions. I figure the mechanism inside prevents that, but how exactly?

Comment: Aren't *both* of the directions locked when the handle is in-between?

Comment: if you're really tricksy, you can unlock three corners if you move the handle between states with it not closed properly ;) I can't find a good diagram to explain how it unlocks two of three possible corners with each handle direction - but you really shouldn't worry, they're designed to not be able to fall right out, no matter how you do it. Handle in the centre is closed, each direction activates a different sub-set of the mechanism & it's designed to not be able to shift the handle whilst it's open in either way, so you can't really get between states unless you don't close it properly.

Comment: Actually had that once (in a decade), and these were pretty big, two thirds of the height type windows. There's one corner that will always stay connected, so I quickly caught it and wiggled the mechanism until it got back in. I think the main trick is in pushing it to a good close, and only then turning the handle (while maintaining a bit of perpendicular pressure on said handle).

Comment: @MiG - yes, mine is pretty big - 6' x 4' perhaps - big enough to get a very large sofa through, which is why it's there, you can't get a sofa up the stairs ;) You just have to make sure it's fully closed before switching the other way, there's just enough flexibility in the structure that it *can* fail to tie all four corners if you're sloppy.

Comment: @MiG "One corner is fixed" sounds like a reasonable answer to me.

Comment: Anti gravity magic is the best explanation

Comment: I would not count on consumer products being idiot proof.  Presume there is *no* protection in the intermediate position.

Comment: @FreeMan how to catch it when it's wrong is definitely part of the answer, but looking at the question I'm guessing it's about how the internal mechanism works. I've not been able to find a good copyright free illustration or photo yet I'm afraid.

Comment: Alright, gave it a go using words :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THE MECHANISM**

Rotating the handle of a tilt and turn mechanism causes a sliding action inside the window frame, which actually goes around the frame's corners. There are multiple sets of locking pins that secure the window in place and additionally tighten the seals around the edge.

With the **first quarter rotation**, these move to an open position. The hinge below the handle is not connected at this point (and the top hinge on the opposite corner is), so the window can **turn**.

At the **second quarter rotation**, this hinge also slides to an open position, and simultaneously the bottom hinge fastens again, so that it can **tilt**.

**SAFETY**

**One corner is continuously attached** to the window frame: the bottom one opposite the hinge. The top hinge is accompanied by a **scissoring mechanism**, that, when fully extended, prevents the tilt window from making more than a (usually) 15 degree angle, and unless great force is in play, should also prevent the entire window from falling on the floor, and, well, people. Furthermore, when fully closed, the extra sets of locking pins provide additional safety (and make burglary even more difficult).

Unless mishandled, the top hinge does not open up until the bottom hinge is secured in place, so the chance of three points coming loose is negligible.

**PREVENTION**

I have actually had the situation above once though. I suspect this was because I engaged the rotating mechanism while the window was not fully closed. Wether this is a vulnerability or not, probably depends on which manufacturer and exact mechanism used. Yours might be fine.

Despite the weight of the window the problem was also quickly solved (and without damage): I maneuvered the tilt frame back into the outer frame, and rotated the handle back and forth until it latched on everywhere.

To prevent this from ever happening, **slightly push the tilt frame** with the other hand (so that it is definitely fully closed), while rotating the handle.